# Is it it possible to fix Windows headers (winnt.h, windefs.h) so they can be compiled with /Za?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm developing an application for multiple platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X) and I want to make sure my code complies to ISO C++ standard. On Linux and Mac it's achieved with `-pedantic-errors` flag, on Windows - with `/Za` flag (disable language extensions). The problem is, some Windows headers are not C++-compliant (and in a silly way, nothing major - most errors are `'$' : unexpected in macro definition`, `'__forceinline' not permitted on data declarations` and similar nonsense). Do you think it would be possible to fix the headers? Has anyone tried that?

Comment: The only practical reason to require ISO C++ compliance is to help create portable code. If that is what you are doing, then you won't be including the Windows headers because they are not available on non-windows platforms. 
Conversely if you are writing windows-only code, you should accept that you will be using the Microsoft toolchain, and windows-specific things are to be expected.    In other words: "Stop messing about and get back to work" :-)

Comment: @Ben: you've missed the point.

Comment: Allow me to paraphrase.... Violet: "I want my boat to take a standard ISO shipping container". Ben: "Really? It looks like a passenger boat, are you planning to ever put a standard shipping container on it?" Violet: "No, just passengers". Ben: "Then WTF do you want it to take a shipping container for? Concentrate on the passenger features!".... Now substitute boat -> code, container -> ISO C++, passengers -> Windows.

Comment: You can disable the `/Za` flag for specific .cpp files, so you could isolate all the Windows-specific stuff to one file and turn off the flag for only that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is impossible. For a lovely discussion on the matter started by STL (the guy, not the acronym) on the Clang developers mailing list see [here](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-June/021886.html).

That being said, if you want to write standard conforming code, I suggest using [MinGW-w64 GCC](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds) on Windows, which provides its own Win32 API headers that can be compiled with `-std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`. I can even [offer you Clang 3.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/clang-3.2-release/). It's 32-bit only and relies on GCC 4.6's libstdc++, but they get along quite well. I have a Clang 3.3 build on my computer at home but libstdc++ and Clang disagree on some variadic template linking issues, so I haven't uploaded it.

Comment: Huh... Bravo Microsoft. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to write a portable code - do it. Your windows headers have nothing to do with it. After you port your code to Linux for example you'll not have them so do not bother.

It is your code (that one that you write) that must be portable so do not worry about **__forceinline** within some header that will not even be on any different platform that you may use.

So - do not bother about warnings that are not from your code.

**Update:**
If these generate warnings you may supress them. If errors you may try the following:

- as for **_forceinlilne** this is (at least in different compilers) just a suggestion for the compiler to try as hard to inline sth - but cannot force it - you may delete it safely if you really need to
- as for other errors - please give an example

Comment: These are not warnings, these are errors. They make it impossible to compile my code in the first place. Of course I don't worry about Windows headers as long they don't prevent my code from compiling.

Comment: @Violet: the point is that you shouldn't be including the Windows headers from any source file that is compiled with /Za.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That much is obvious, but I want to compile _all_ my code with extensions disabled, not only non-Windows.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: well, OK, fair enough; you can want to as much as you like.  You still shouldn't do it.  (IMO, the question you need to ask yourself is this: do I want code that conforms to a theoretical standard, or code that will actually be supported to run on the target operating system?)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a mingw/cygwin gcc with the winapi headers that ship with them. They are not complete, so you might need to copy some declarations from the Windows SDK if you are using newer stuff. But, as others mentioned, your code is already not portable if you are using the windows headers.